# React Native Navigation from Child Components

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-native-navigation

I'm trying to implement a simple navigation between screens, but getting this error:

***`Undefined is not an object 'this.props.navigate'`***

**`AppNavigator.js`**

```
let AppNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  Signup: 
  { screen: SignupScreen, 
    navigationOptions: {
      header: null
    }

  },
  Login: { screen: LoginScreen,
    navigationOptions: {
      header: null
    } 
  },
},{
  initialRouteName: "Signup"
});
```

**`SignupScreen.js`**

```
<View>
 <SignupForm/>
</View>
```

**`SignupForm.js`**

```
const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
<Text onPress={() =>
       navigate('Login')
}>
 ¿Allready have an account? Sign in
</Text>
```

I guess the problem is that there si something additional to do in child components cases. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should pass `navigation` to `SignupForm`. Choose 1 of 2 solution below

1.

```
<View>
 <SignupForm navigation={this.props.navigation} />
</View>
```

**or**

2. in SignupForm.js

```
import { withNavigation } from 'react-navigation';

export default withNavigation(SignupForm);
```

Comment: Used the first solution (after trying a lot of stuff including the second solution).. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You must use withNavigation if you use separate component see the documentation about withNavigation : [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/with-navigation.html)

Answer (score 0):

You might have missed wrapping your `AppNavigator` in a `NavigationContainer` before using it elsewhere.

in your **AppNavigator.js**

```
import { createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation'; // add this
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack'; // i trust you've already got this

let AppNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  Signup: 
  { screen: SignupScreen, 
    navigationOptions: {
      header: null
    }    
  },
  Login: { screen: LoginScreen,
    navigationOptions: {
      header: null
    } 
  },
},{
  initialRouteName: "Signup"
});

export default createAppContainer(AppNavigator); // this is important!
```

I actually don't think there's anything special you need to do for child components to work. That `AppContainer` is for ensuring correct props are passed to child components. Refer to [documentation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/hello-react-navigation.html#creating-a-stack-navigator) for a bit more context.