# React native custom component with Stacknavigator

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm new to react native.
So what I understand about the stack navigator is that you can switch from view to view by defining the routes in the app like this:

```
 import React from 'react';
 import {createAppContainer} from 'react-navigation';
 import {createStackNavigator} from 'react-navigation-stack';

 import MenuScreen from "./views/MenuScreen";
 import HomeScreen from "./views/HomeScreen";
 import OrderScreen from "./views/OrderScreen";
 import PaymentScreen from "./views/PaymentScreen";
 import ReseedScreen from "./views/ReseedScreen";
 import ConfirmationScreen from "./views/ConfirmationScreen";


const MainNavigator = createStackNavigator({
    Home: {screen: HomeScreen},
    Menu: {screen: MenuScreen},
    Order: {screen: OrderScreen},
    Payment: {screen: PaymentScreen},
    Reseed: {screen: ReseedScreen},
    confirmation: {screen: ConfirmationScreen},
});

const App = createAppContainer(MainNavigator);
```

and then in the MenuScreen file like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Button } from 'react-native';

export default class MenuScreen extends React.Component {
static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Welcome', // Add stuff at the top of page
};
render() {
    const {navigate} = this.props.navigation;
    return (
        <Button
            title="some title"
            onPress={() => navigate('Home', {name: 'home'})}
        />
    );
}
}
```

What works fine and create a button where if I click it it goes toward the homescreen and its create a back button. So I wanted to create a component called navbar where I just put multiple button in so I can use that in all mine screens. this is how the navbar.js looks.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {View, Button, Text} from 'react-native';

export default class NavBar extends Component {

static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Welcome', // Add stuff at the top of page
};

render = () => {
    const {navigate} = this.props.navigation;

    return (
        <View>
            <Text>Nav bar</Text>
            <Button
                title="Go to home screen"
                onPress={() => navigate('Home', {name: 'home'})}
            />
            <Button
                title="Go to home screen"
                onPress={() => navigate('Menu', {name: 'menu'})}
            />
            <Button
                title="Go to home screen"
                onPress={() => navigate('Order', {name: 'Order'})}
            />
        </View>
    );
}
}
```

and then the update MenuScreen.js with the custom NavBar component

```
import React from 'react';
import { Button, View } from 'react-native';
import NavBar from "./components/navbar";

export default class MenuScreen extends React.Component {
static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Welcome', // Add stuff at the top of page
};
render() {
    const {navigate} = this.props.navigation;
    return (
        // <Button
        //     title="some title"
        //     onPress={() => navigate('Home', {name: 'home'})}
        // />
        <View>
            <NavBar></NavBar>
        </View>
    );
}
}
```

but the navbar.js returns a `type error` navigate is not defined

```
      7 |     title: 'Welcome', // Add stuff at the top of page
      8 | };
      9 | 
   > 10 | render = () => {
| ^  11 |     const {navigate} = this.props.navigation;
     12 | 
     13 |     return (
```

So if I understand this correctly it returns the error cause the `navbar.js` is not defined in the `app.js`. But the `navbar.js` is not a screen but should be a component so do I need to import something extra into the `navbar.js` or is it not possible to use the stack navigator to make a component out of that?

folder structure:

```
app.js
views/MenuScreen.js
views/components/NavBar.js
```

Comment: where did you put `NavBar`?

Comment: the screens is in `views/` and the `navbar` is in `views/components` also will update the question

Comment: It may related to one of my answer. Please check https://stackoverflow.com/a/59222680/8268484.

Comment: that actually the solution adding the `withNavigation()` to the export default then it works

Answer (score 2):

What i would suggest is you disable the default navigation options, that is backbutton on top and create your own component just to navigate as your way.

first step is to disable the header for all screens by adding below code in you stack navigator :

defaultNavigationOptions: {
      headerShown: false,
    },

like

```
const MainNavigator = createStackNavigator({
    Home: {screen: HomeScreen},
    Menu: {screen: MenuScreen},
    Order: {screen: OrderScreen},
    Payment: {screen: PaymentScreen},
    Reseed: {screen: ReseedScreen},
    confirmation: {screen: ConfirmationScreen},
},{
defaultNavigationOptions: {
      headerShown: false,
    },

});
```

and now you can create your component like you have created navbar.js.

And now suppose you want to use it in HomeScreen.js  so first you do

```
import Navbar from './NavBar.js';



    class HomeScreen extends Component {


    render(){
    return(
    <Navbar navigation={this.props.navigation} />
    // then rest of your code
    )
    }
    }
```

with this it should work and plus you have flexibility and can change style of navbar.js. 
hope it helps. feel free for doubts

Comment: It still says the navigation in the NavBar.js  is undefined. Am I maybe still missing something with importing or passing the variable navigation to the NavBar.js?

Comment: are you importing navbar correctly? in your homescreen.js?

Comment: yes the import is correct its returns the same error where it says the navigate is undefined

Comment: can you share all your code in an expo snack? ill check there

Comment: https://snack.expo.io/BkQjTkZ0B .  hey check this link, feel free for doubts. ill explain you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204188/discussion-between-gaurav-roy-and-hashtagforgotname).

Comment: the problem was already solved the comment on the post was the solution like Tuan luong lined

Answer (score 0):

render should be normal function instead of arrow function.

```
render(){

}
```